# data not getting as per the id selected

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-2

here are my tables namely `tbl_tools`and `tbl_tool_use`.
the `tbl_tools` table looks like this

```
id  name            quantity    available   type        
5   cutting player     5          5        engineer     
6   reflectors         2          2        team     
7   spanner            8          8        engineer     
8   tester             4          4        team
```

the `tbl_tool_use` looks like this

```
id  user_id     type       tool_id    quantity  start_date  end_date
92     27      engineer     7,5         2,4          2016-12-24
```

here is my code for updating

```
            $t_id = $this->input->post('tool_id'); //array of id
            $qty = $this->input->post('quantity'); //array or qty
            $updateArray = array();
            for($x = 0; $x < sizeof($t_id); $x++){
             $updateArray[] = array(
             'id'=>$t_id[$x],
             'available' => $qty[$x]

             );
             }      
             $this->db->update_batch('tbl_tools',$updateArray, 'id');
```

Here is my code please have alook.

```
public function edit_available($tool_id=null,$quantity=null)
{



    $tool_id=array(7,5);
    $quantity=array(2,4);


    $this->db->where_in('id',$tool_id);
    $data=array('available'=>$quantity);
    $query=$this->db->update('tbl_tools',$data);
    if($query)
    {
            return true;
    }
    else
    {
            return false;
    }
}
```

the `tool_id` given here are `7` and `5` and the quantity selected are `2` and `4` respectively.when i used my code only the first value of the `quantity` is getting changed in both `id`,s.need to change as per the id selected please help me to solve my problem

Comment: when calling update, `$data` looks like   `array('available' => array(3,2))`, so the `db->update` command is updating `available` eq `array(3,2)` in `tbl_tools`.  Since the db field doesn't take `array`, and is likely an int field, it is being reduced to the first valid int value it can parse from the array.

Comment: how can we change that..please help me

Comment: I don't work with CodeIgniter, but I don't believe you should be passing nested arrays as the update value.  I believe it is a 1:1 key=>value  system if anything. Reading up on it now.

Comment: I was correct.  Please review [CodeIgniter db->update documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html#update)

Answer (score 2):

**First make array of tool id and quantity descrired below**

```
$data = array(
       array(
          'id' => '7' ,
          'available' => '3'
       ),
       array(
          'id' => '5' ,
          'available' => '2' ,
       )
    );
```

**And then perform batch update**

```
$this->db->update_batch('tbl_tools', $data, 'id');
```

**Reference: How to make multi dimensional array**

```
$tool_id=array(7,5);
$quantity=array(3,2);
$data = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($tool_id as $t){
   $data[$i]['id'] = $t;
   $data[$i]['available'] = $quantity[$i];
   $i++;
}
```

Comment: @MOHAMMED: if you don't know how to make multi dimensional array then let me know

Comment: This looks good.   A quick question after looking at the docs >  Are you sure the 3rd param can accept a single field name with no assignment direction ?  (only implied through matching it to the respective nested array value group with a key of the same name for lookup ?)

Comment: the idea and the logic i got it clear now but how can we do it dynamically..am not much great to make multi dimensional array

Comment: @SamuelJackson :https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#updating-data

Comment: i think u have idea about how to use foreach loop and by using it u can make multi dimensional array

Comment: yaa..i have idea of foreach loop

Comment: So use $tool_id in foreach loop and make it m.d. array

Comment: Sorry, but perhaps I am blind tonight.  I am only seeing tertiary parameters in reference to setting inside the 3rd param.  `$this->db->update('mytable', $data, "id = 4");`  and  `$this->db->update('mytable', $data, array('id' => $id));`  I don't see anything in the docs which implies the 3rd param could be used as a field only to identify and cascade data from an MD array passed on the second param.

Comment: have you referred the link which i have provided?

Comment: Yes, which is the same information as what I provided in comments to "MOHAMMED"   ( /facepalm....  `update_batch`  not `update`[which is where i was looking].    said i was blind tonight  :)   nice job  :)  )

Comment: @dhruvjadia thanks but i have a doubt how can we update here with id

Comment: just pass id as 3rd parameter it automatically generate query for this

Comment: i had used another code and added it please have a look

Comment: yaaa the result is not getting